# WinRT - loading a system DLL for Print Notifications

Tags: c#, printing, windows-runtime, dllimport

I'm currently developing a Windows Store Device App in C#, part of which requires support for Print Notifications (via the PrintNotificationHandler background task).

This particular task delivers an  element which contains elements which require access to external DLLs (in particular, the PrintConfig.dll standard dll).  With the DLL name and a StringID you are intended to be able to determine the actual string.

However, WinRT expressly prohibits accessing any DLL that's not included in it's Resources.  I've tried using a separate Win32 DLL to do the resource loading for me (via GetModuleFileName/LoadLibrary) but these calls appear to be prohibited if the DLL is build with "Windows Store App Support" set to yes.

Does anyone have an idea if there is a standard way to do this in WinRT?  Or if there is a workaround for getting the DLL to build for Windows Store Apps which would allow for LoadLibrary?

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably the way forward is to implement the functionality in a store app manner rather than a desktop app manner

Comment: This functionality was actually expressly for a windows store app - microsoft sample code which is intended to walk through this very path goes so far as retrieving the XML notification data (which specifies the StringID and ResourceDLL to use) but never actually tries to retrieve a string from it.  That functionality is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Which is why I wonder why you feel you have to load native DLLs. Surely theres a store app approach to solve your problem.